# SBT: How to set transitive dependencies of a dependency to "provided" later?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I have something like this in my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val someDeps = Seq(
  libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "foo" % "1.3.37",
  // more
)

lazy val some_library = project.in(file("libs/somelibrary")).
  settings(commonSettings).
  settings(
    // project-specific settings
    libraryDependencies ++= someDeps
  )

lazy val something_with_deps_provided = project.in(file("swdp")).
  settings(commonSettings).
  settings(
    // project-specific settings
    libraryDependencies ++= someDeps.map(d => d % "provided")
  ).dependsOn(some_library)
```

When I now use the `sbt-assembly-plugin` to create the assembly of `something_with_deps_provided`, it still puts the dependencies into the resulting jar, ignoring the `provided`. Is it possible to set a transitive dependency to `provided` later and if yes, how is it done?

Comment: Have you figured it out ? I guess you could exclude said depedencies, and the add them back as provided, but it is kind of hacky.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, `excludeDependencies` can be used as described in
SBT manual here:
[Exclude Transitive Dependencies](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies).

With your example:

```
lazy val something_with_deps_provided = project.in(file("swdp"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .dependsOn(some_library)
  .settings(
    // project-specific settings
    excludeDependencies ++= someDeps.map { d => 
      ExclusionRule(
        organization = d.organization,
        name         = d.name
      )
    }
  )
```

The dependencies from `someDeps` will no longer be included in the
assembly JAR for `something_with_deps_provided` project.